# Entity Framework - Make the generated signatures of procedures and function not dependent on EF

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, dependency-management

this is Entity Framework 6.1.3.

I want to be able to extract an `interface` for my stored procedures. And I want this interface to not have any dependency on the EntityFramwork.dll assembly, so I can expose it to the client layers in an abstract way, so they don't have awareness/reference/dependency to Entity Framework.

The problem is that EF puts classes like `ObjectResult` and `ObjectParameter` in the generated method signature. And those classes are defined in the assembly EntityFramework.dll, so it injects the dependenecy on the extracted interface, which is what I want to avoid.

I solved the `ObjectResult`problem this way: I have edited the `MyEntities.Context.tt` file, and inside the method `public string FunctionMethod(EdmFunction edmFunction, string modelNamespace, bool includeMergeOption)` I found a line that was originally this:

```
returnType == null ? "int" : "ObjectResult<" + _typeMapper.GetTypeName(returnType, modelNamespace) + ">",
```

So I changed it to this:

```
returnType == null ? "int" : "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<" + _typeMapper.GetTypeName(returnType, modelNamespace) + ">",
```

So the return type for the generated procedures is no longer `ObjectResult<>`, but `IEnumerable<>`, which is great.

But I couldn't manage to solve the problem for the `ObjectParameter` cases. Those are generated by EF when we have an Output parameter (or InOut parameter). I'd like to replace the defaultly-generated `ObjectParameter myParam` in the method signature for `ref int myParam`, for example. And keep the ObjectParameter handling inside the method code, not in it's signature. So the each method should create internally the ObjectParameter and put the returned value in the out/ref method parameters.

I tried hard but couldn't find a way do edit the `MyEntities.Context.tt` in such a way. Maybe someone with a better knowledge of T4 and EF can present an easy solution...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to define the interface in a way that suits your clients the most, and to have an implementation that adapts to the code that EF requires.

In other words, don't try to squeeze a round peg in a square hole by editing your T4 template or abusing EF. Instead create an independent implementation that wraps EF or delegates the call to EF and transforms the returned data in a way that suits the interface. This implementation will probably contain just a few lines of code, since it only has to deal with the transformation -or- alternatively, since you're dealing with a stored procedure, remove EF completely from the equation and call the SP directly through ADO.NET. Modelling this SP through EF might not make much sense.

Comment: That's what I am currently doing. I currently have wrapper methods defined in a partial class file that "translates" the calls to the EF generated methods, whenever their original signature is not suitable. The problem is my DB has exactly 2364 procedures, so this will not scale well long-term. To manually create a wrapper method for each one would be unfeasible. Auto-generated code is the way to go for my case. It makes sense to use EF to call these procedures because EF generates POCO DTO classes for their return types, which are great to use in my business and view layers.

Comment: 2364 SPs? Wow. That will be a challenge. Good luck with that.

Comment: Thanks! The system is decades old... There's also thousands of tables, triggers, functions... Everything is very coupled with the DB. I'm trying to rejuvenate things by migrating everything to a .NET architecture using EF, rewriting the logic from the procedures into business classes, but it's impossible to decouple from all of the SPs so easily, so I still have to call a lot of them.

Comment: I encountered such system a few years back. What I advised the team was to wrap these stored procedures in [command/handler pairs](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and [query/handler pairs](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92), while keeping those SPs in tact initially. This allowed them to cut away a massive amount of cross-cutting code that was tangled with business code. This made the system much more adaptable and maintainable, because it become childs play to add cross-cutting concerns like caching, validation, or security  checks.